# Javascript: how to detect array calls?

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods, native

I have question about native javascript calling.

i have a class:

```
x = function(arr) { this.arr = arr; return this; }
x.prototype.toArray = function() {
       return this.arr;
};
x.prototype.test = function() { alert('but i m object too!'); };
```

when i calling:

```
var test = new x(['a','b','c']);

alert(test[0]);

alert(test.test());
```

need to get result 'a' and 'but i m object too!' dialogs.

I want to use this feature as **syntax sugar** like uses jquery in core when returning DOM Elements after using selector as array. How to implement that?

UPDATE:

Thank for answer, but i need **proofs in jquery code blob on github**.

Comment: Do you want your object to be *like* an array or "inherit" all the methods that an array has?

Comment: @Jack My guess is *like* an array. Like how you can get the DOM element from a jQuery object using `$('selector')[0]`

Comment: Another way, i think.. i can extend Array object and write here my native methods from x.prototype... but it is "context dancing" :-)

Comment: *"Thank for answer, but i need proofs in jquery code blob on github."* No one is preventing you from looking at the source code: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core/init.js#L16. But if you want to do it exactly how jQuery does it, why did you asked the question in the first place? You could have just looked at the source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the jQuery prototype only has a `length` property and that makes it array-like; to "import" items into it, they must be copied one by one.

To perform this merge, they use the [following function](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L391):

```
function merge(first, second) 
{
  var len = +second.length,
  j = 0,
  i = first.length;

  for ( ; j < len; j++ ) {
    first[ i++ ] = second[ j ];
  }

  first.length = i;

  return first;
}
```

Next, they define the [constructor](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L27) which can also be called as a function:

```
function x(arr)
{
    return new x.fn.init(arr);
}
```

The `x.fn` refers to a [prototype](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L42) from which the functions are inherited, as shown below:

```
x.fn = x.prototype = {
  constructor: x,
  test: function() {
    alert('yay');
  },
  init: function(arr) {
    return merge(this, arr);
  },
  length: 0
};
```

As you can see, your `test()` method is also there, together with an initialized `length` property. The only thing that remains is to [bind](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core/init.js#L116) the `x.fn.init` prototype to the above `x.fn`:

```
x.fn.init.prototype = x.fn;
```

With all that in place, the following code works as expected:

```
var y = x(['a', 'b', 'c']);

alert(y[0]); // shows 'a'
y.test(); // alerts 'yay'
```

Comment: Thanks for complete answer!

Answer (score 3):

An array is nothing else than an object which treats numeric properties in a special way. You would have to copy every element of the array to the instance, using the index of the element as property name. You should also set the `length` attribute, to make it a true "array-like" object.

```
var X = function(arr) {
    for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
        this[i] = arr[i];
    }
    this.length = arr.length;
};

var x = new X(['a', 'b', 'c']);
alert(x[0]);
```

Comment: and jquery using that way?

Answer (score 0):

Why didn't you call toArray() that you have created?

Try:

```
x = function(arr) { this.arr = arr; }
x.prototype.toArray = function() {
       return this.arr;
};

var test = new x(['a','b','c']);

alert(test.toArray()[0]);
```

OR

```
x = function(arr) { this.arr = arr; }
x.prototype.toArray = function() {
       return this.arr;
};

var test = new x(['a','b','c']).toArray();

alert(test[0]);
```

Comment: This is still not what the OP wants.